# how to substring of a string in SQL

Tags: sql

My data will be like that

```
IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC.txt
IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC_05.txt
IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC_01.txt
```

I would like to extract **clearGAC.txt** from above.
How can I use substring in SQL ?

Comment: What do you expect as result for each record?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - > What do you mean?

Comment: @juergend - > MS SQL 2008 Express.

Comment: @kevin: What do you want to extract? Do you want to check if this field contains `clearGAC.txt` or do you want to get the part behind(f.e. `05` or `01`) or do you want the previous part(f.e. `test_20120409`)? It makes no sense to "extract" a hardcoded value(`SELECT 'clearGAC.txt' AS Foo FROM Table)`.

Comment: I am going to pass ClearGAC.txt and see if it's in the DB.
this ClearGAC.txt may be named like above codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I assume that you want the _05 and _01** - the question is not clear.

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(250)

DECLARE @table TABLE ( val VARCHAR(250) )
INSERT  INTO @table
        SELECT  'IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC_01.txt'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC_05.txt'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC.txt' 


SELECT  SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX('clearGAC', val), 50),
        SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX('_', val)+1, 50), CHARINDEX('_', SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX('_', val)+1, 50))+1, 50)
FROM    @table
```

Returns this:

```
clearGAC_01.txt
clearGAC_05.txt
clearGAC.txt
```

The third parameter in the CHARDINDEX can be larger than the length.

**EDIT:** I added logic if you don't know if `clearGAC` is the name

After reading your comment, you may just want this:

> I am going to pass ClearGAC.txt and see if it's in the DB. this
>   ClearGAC.txt may be named like above codes.

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(250)

DECLARE @table TABLE ( val VARCHAR(250) )
INSERT  INTO @table
        SELECT  'IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC_01.txt'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC_05.txt'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC.txt' 


SELECT  *
FROM    @table
WHERE   val LIKE '%clearGAC%.txt'
```

Comment: Depends on what you want.  Per your comment, you just want to see if there are any clearGAC's in the database.  That being true, a LIKE is much better.  Where a substring is calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC.txt', CHARINDEX('09_','IPDocument/XR/test_20120409_clearGAC.txt')+3, 100)
```

result : 
clearGAC.txt

Comment: Thanks . but I will only know the clearGAC.txt name. not the exact date.